# C++ warning: address of local variable 'tab2' returned. How to fix?

Tags: c++, string, variables, memory, char

i am new to c++ so please take me easy. I am trying to write a function which takes a string and converts it to a `char*` to send that eventually over socket:

```
char* str_to_char(std::string string){
    char tab2[buflen];
    strncpy(tab2, string.c_str(), sizeof(tab2));
    tab2[sizeof(tab2) - 1] = '\0';
    return tab2;
}
```

but compiler says:

```
test.cpp:24:10: warning: address of local variable 'tab2' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     char tab2[buflen];
          ^~~~
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: `tab2` exists in the context of `str_to_char`. When you return, the variable goes out of scope and you can no longer access the data (technically you can, but it is UB and unlike some other cases this will really quickly bite you in the rear). Use heap allocation or better yet `std::string` for this. Probably other standard containers such as `std::array` work too

Comment: Why is "Do not return the address of a local variable." not the answer? It is a bad idea. What ever you try to do that way cannot work reliably.

Comment: @Yunnosch in reality, it can. `send()` function requires a `char*` to hold the data. I can't just use 'c_str()' since i can't insert a null terminator, causing undefined behaviour and so receiving weird bytes on server-side. So i need a function to do this.

Comment: @user4581301 i have gcc 6.3.0, i can guarantee you that if i use `send()` with `c_str()` i am receiving extra bad-decoded bytes after the data, it's a shame we can't pass `std::string` as parameter for `send()`.

Comment: If you `send(sockfd, str.c_str(), str.size(), some_flags);`, note that `size` does not include the null terminator. Otherwise you could be having any number of common misconceptions about the sending and receiving of data via TCP. For example, not processing `send`'s (or `recv`'s) return code and assuming everything you wanted sent (or received) was sent (or received). I'm pretty sure you're asking about the wrong thing and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: string.c_str includes a null terminator for you - can you please show us the code that was not working when you tried to send from a `std::string.c_str()`

Answer (score 2):

> C++ warning: address of local variable 'tab2' returned. How to fix?

By not returning a pointer (nor a reference, nor an iterator) that points to an automatic object that is destroyed when the function exits.

> I am trying to write a function which takes a string and converts it to a char*

You don't need to write such a function. `std::string` already has member functions that do that. They are called `c_str()` and `data()`.

> send() function requires a char* to hold the data

You can use the POSIX standard `send()` like this:

```
send(
    sockfd,
    string.c_str(),
    string.size() + 1, // +1 is for sending the null terminator
    flags);
```

Comment: you don't know how much you helped me. I have been struggled for day on this weird problem, really thank you! For some reason it doesn't work with `sizeof(string)` instead of `string.size()`

Comment: @vik Of course it wouldn't work with `sizeof(string)`. That is the size of the `std::string` type. It has nothing to do with the size of the buffer that the instance manages.